# How to create a cart with Django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm coding a REST API with Django REST framework I want to create a cart for a coffee shop with Django rest but I don't know how to create views and serializers.py for my project . I created my models and the cart class but I can't write views.py and Serializers.py and urls.py please help me .

this is my model and cart class:

#models.py

```
from django.db import models
from coffishop import settings


class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    info = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='orders')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user} - {str(self.id)}'

    def get_total_price(self):
        total = sum(item.get_cost() for item in self.items.all())
 


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='items')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='order_items')
    price = models.IntegerField()
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    def get_cost(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity
```

#cart class

```
from menu.models import Food


CART_SESSION_ID = 'cart'
class Cart:
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get(CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart:
            cart = self.session[CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.cart = cart

    def __iter__(self):
        food_ids = self.cart.keys()
        foods = Food.objects.filter(id__in=food_ids)
        cart = self.cart.copy()
        for food in foods:
            cart[str(food.id)]['food'] = food

        for item in cart.values():
            item['total_price'] = int(item['price']) * item['quantity']
            yield item

    def remove(self, product):
        food_id = str(food.id)
        if food_id in self.cart:
            del self.cart[food_id]
            self.save()

    def add(self, food, quantity):
        food_id = str(food.id)

        if food_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[food_id] = {'quantity':0, 'price':str(food.price)}
        self.cart[food_id]['quantity'] += quantity
        self.save()

    def save(self):
        self.session.modified = True

    def get_total_price(self):
        return sum(int(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def clear(self):
        del self.session[CART_SESSION_ID]
        self.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow DRF rest documentation. I am mentioning some of resources

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#creating-a-serializer-class

https://realpython.com/django-rest-framework-quick-start/#drf-quick-start

http://www.cdrf.co/

If you want to reuse your cart class then https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#class-based-views

serializer.py used for serializing your request and response structure. Its coupled with your django models.
Views.py handles your business logic where you can make use of cart class by using REST methods.
urls.py to expose your API end point

Comment: I read them before. I know what view and serializer mean  I know the concept but I still can not code my own . I should practice more but I do not have much time to do this project

Comment: I can help you to add your views. I don't know your complete requirement. I can drive the way to continue. You can directly use the Views.py

Comment: thank you for your helping. I want the users that they registered in my web site before can order foods and they have a cart for adding some another food or updating and removing they order. and I show them the total price and after that they guide to pay the price. I write the serializer by using the Model Serializers you help me to complete the views please.

Comment: if you able to write sterilizer then use model specific generic views. just combine your sterilizer with your views. you are done https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/

Answer (score 0):

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class CartAPI(APIView):
    """
    
    """
  
    
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        """
        Return a list of all users.
        """
        cart=Cart(request)
        ## call required method
        ## for response https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#creating-responses
        return Response({"data": data}, status=Status.OK) 
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
       """
       """
       cart=Cart(request)
       ## call required method
       return Response()
```